# my sql questions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

THIS is the table for the questions

```
+---------+----------+------+
| owner   | species  | sex  |
+---------+----------+------+
| Harry   | cat      | f    |
| Gwen    | dog      | m    |
| Adlai   | rat      | m    |
| Alex    | bird     | f    |
| Harry   | dog      | f    |
| Gwen    | cat      | m    |
| Gwen    | dog      | f    |
+---------+----------+------+
```

I have tried >

```
SELECT owner,MAX(count(species)) FROM pet GROUP BY owner;
```

did not get it.

i managed to get >

```
SELECT owner, count(species)  FROM pets GROUP BY owner;
+---------+----------------+
| owner   | count(species) |
+---------+----------------+
| Gwen    |              3 |
| Adlai   |              1 |
| Harry   |              2 |
| Alex    |              1 |
+---------+----------------+
```

but it needs only one... 
please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't you just ask the exact same question a few minutes ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577345/mysql-query-in-table

Comment: it was not formated well, first time so...

Comment: What is the "it" that you are trying to get?

Comment: Is it my imagination or is there no actual question being asked here?

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
  SELECT owner
    FROM pet
   WHERE species IN ('cat', 'dog')
GROUP BY owner
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This query assumes the owner can only have a single cat and a single dog.

1a.

```
    SELECT p1.owner
      FROM pet p1
INNER JOIN p2 ON p1.owner = p2.owner
             AND p2.pet = 'dog'
     WHERE p1.pet = 'cat'
  GROUP BY p1.owner
```

This query is slightly better since it doesn't care of how many pets every owner has.

2.

```
  SELECT owner, count(species) cnt
    FROM pets
GROUP BY owner
ORDER BY count(species) DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

PS: and try to do your homework next time by yourself ;-)

Comment: I think that giving a solution of hard-coded fixed values per this example was a bad option.  What if one other person had (turtle, snake, aligator, monkey, spider) for pets... they would not even qualify in your 1a example.

Comment: @DRapp: "they would not even qualify in your 1a example" --- you can perform several joins. Thanks for -1. Btw, programmers solve real issue. The current issue - is a homework with a particular values.

Comment: I typically don't down vote, but thought that was a really bad example.  Even with multiple joins, would you do for every type of species?...  What if someone had cat, fish, dog, horse, and another had turtle, snake, aligator, spider... each owner would BOTH have 4 species and neither has an overlapping species in common.

Comment: @DRapp: we can think of imaginary cases for hours, but I'm as a software engineer provide a solutions that fit the requirements. That easy. My query: 1. does what it expected 2. can be optimized **easily**. Good luck on running your query on something with at least 10M rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding specific species, what it looks like you are asking for is...  Of the owners of pets, I want to know who has the most distinct species regardless of sexual gender (m/f).  Whatever that count is, you want to list all owners who had that # of species.  Start first with getting the highest distinct species count per ANY owner, ANY species...

However, by re-reading, it looks like you are considering Gwen as 3 species even though 2 are dogs, 1 is a cat, but the dogs are one male, one female...  What if someone has 4 dogs and they are all male and 5 cats all female.  Would that count as 2 species?

Anyhow, based on my original based on distinct SPECIES (regardless of gender), I have a solution

```
select
      PreQuery.owner,
      PreQuery.SpeciesCount,
      @HighCount := if( @HighCount < PreQuery.SpeciesCount, 
           PreQuery.SpeciesCount, @HighCount ) as KeepCount
   from
      ( select 
              owner, 
              count( distinct species ) as SpeciesCount
           from 
              pets
           group by 
              owner
           order by 
              count( distinct species ) desc ) PreQuery,
      ( select @HighCount := 0 ) sqlvars
   having
      SpeciesCount = KeepCount
```

at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/597cb/8)

The first query pre-aggregates the number of DISTINCT species regardless of gender and orders with the highest count coming first.  By using MySQL Variables (via @varName), I am applying the first record returned in the result set to the high count value, then keep it there for all subsequent records.

Finally, the "HAVING" clause allows it to retain only those that had that max count.. in this scenario, it had TWO people with two distinct species.

If you DO want it based on species AND sex, we can revise the query, but the principle will be the same.

[Another query based on distinct species AND sex](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/597cb/10)

I just changed to

```
count( distinct concat(species, sex) )
```

in both places

Comment: The provided "monstruous" query doesn't even return the desired result. The desired - is a list of the owners who has both a cat and a dog.

Comment: @zerkms, I'm not seeing anything in THIS question about wanting cats and dogs, however, looking at the comment about duplicate question and going to THAT one, I do see the context to cat AND dog.  That said, I would try to remove the down vote, but apparently that it locked in.  I can UNdo, but only if your answer is edited (even slightly I guess)

Comment: please look at the history of changes of the question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16577588/revisions (particularly http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16577588/1). "anything in THIS question" -- in the current revision there is no question at all. I'm not sure how it's possible to answer to something that's not even asked.